# Для таблицы Products добавить флаг активности продукта (1 - активен, 0 - закрыт)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Требуется добавить новый столбец, где будут вставлены значения по условию.
ALTER TABLE Products ADD COLUMN Flag ENUM ('1', '0')
Я вставляю новый столбец, а как его теперь заполнить необходимыми значениями по условию, кроме как не в ручную ?

Comment: А зачем вы используете «виртуальные даты»? Ещё и разные. Чем вас NULL не устраивает?

Comment: вы про enum говорите?

Comment: Про 01.01.4444 и 31.12.9999

Comment: таково условие задания, это было по дефолту

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Products SET Flag = '0'; /* по-умолчанию все закрыто*/
UPDATE Products SET Flag = '1' WHERE CloseDate != STR_TO_DATE('01.01.4444', '%d.%m.%Y'); /*или какое там условие активности*/
```

Comment: выдает ошибку SQL Error [1265] [01000]: Data truncated for column 'Flag' at row 1, возможно вся проблема в enum?

Comment: Попробуйте '0' и '1'

Comment: Малость упустил, да, там кавычки важны, отредактировал ответ

Comment: у меня вышло без кавычек ))) только я сделала немного иначе, спасибо вам за помощь !!!   

ALTER TABLE Products ADD COLUMN Flag ENUM ('1', '0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
UPDATE Products SET Flag = 1 WHERE DateClose = '01.01.4444'